How to force MudBlazor Pagination to always be visible despite the size of the Window?
How can I fill the Window with the MudDatagrid but also always show Pagination at the bottom of the screen.
You can recreate my screenshot below by adjusting the size of the TryMud Window.
Stack is asking me to provide more text.  Thank you for your help.
TryMud

